# First post review queue -bug or new feature?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I flagged a post for "unclear what you're asking".

Just a few minutes after, I got the same question on the first post review queue.

Before the change on the flag options, the "I am done" button automatically was used to come activated.

This time, it was not. I tried to flag again (just for testing), but the options were not available. Then, I just pressed "No action needed".

Probably the second, but is this a new feature or a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me... I'll work on finding someone to look into it on our side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now. Flagging the post outside the context of review should pre-enable the "I'm Done" button again.